# Distance moved by Accelerometer

Tags: iphone, xcode, accelerometer, distance

I want to move objects on iPhone screen (rectangle, circle and so on) by moving iPhone. 
For example, I move iPhone along X-axis and the object moves along X-axis. The same for Y,Z-axis.

How can I do this?
Can I get algorithm for it?

Thank you.

P.S:
I looked for a while and seems like it is possible using accelerometer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get position by integrating the linear acceleration twice but **the error is horrible. It is useless in practice.**

Here is [an explanation why (Google Tech Talk)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) at 23:20. I highly recommend this video.

However the **gyro mouse** might work for your application, see between 37:00-38:25 in the video.

Similar questions:

[track small movements of iphone with no GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6158176/341970)
[What is the real world accuracy of phone accelerometers when used for positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6027724/341970)
[how to calculate phone's movement in the vertical direction from rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6291110/341970)
[iOS: Movement Precision in 3D Space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5550453/341970)
[How to use Accelerometer to measure distance for Android Application Development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6352681/341970)
[How can I find distance traveled with a gyroscope and accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6647314/341970)

Answer (score 3):

Not easy to do accurately. An accelerometer only reports *acceleration*, not movement. You can try (numerically) integrating the acceleration over time, but you're likely to end up with cumulative errors adding up and leading to unintended motion.

Pseudocode, obviously untested:

```
init:
    loc = {0, 0, 0}    ; location of object on screen
    vel = {0, 0, 0}    ; velocity of object on screen
    t = 0              ; last time measured

step:
    t0 = time          ; get amount of time since last measurement
    dt = t0 - t
    accel = readAccelerometer()
    vel += accel * dt  ; update velocity
    loc += vel * dt    ; update position
    displayObjectAt(loc)
```

Comment: So you are saying it is not practical thing to do on iphone?

Comment: Correct. The links in Ali's response show that this will probably not work usefully.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the acceleration itself instead distance moved?  For example;
If your acceleration is 1.4G east, your object should move to east 14pixels per second until your acceleration changes.

So that object's movement is will be like it is under a relative force and I think it's more realistic. Faster moving device, bigger force to effect object.

Also look:

http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3397.pdf

and

[Using accelerometer, gyroscope and compass to calculate device's movement in 3D world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264518/using-accelerometer-gyroscope-and-compass-to-calculate-devices-movement-in-3d)

Comment: When you will make a movement, for example to the left, you will get output like this:

-1g
0g
0g
0g
1g

because when you will stop movement you will get force which will be negative to initial force which created movement.

you need to somehow filter it and it isnt easy.