# How to get xy coordinates from three angles from gyroscope data

Tags: java, android, sensors

I am working on a code where i need to convert the three angles coming from gyroscope data i.e. azimuth, pitch  and roll into x and y coordinates on screen which is 2d plane. I have searched but could not find appropriate logic or algorithm to achieve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The gyroscope gives you rotation data - as further explained here: [Motion Sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html), along with some sample code.

What you need is probably the accelerometer, and you can see some answers here, for example: [Read x y z coordinates of android phone using accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068671/read-x-y-z-coordinates-of-android-phone-using-accelerometer).

Comment: Actually i am already using the accelerometer alongside the gyroscope and after filtering the data i am getting the three orientation angles i mentioned above. But now i am stuck as to how to get the position in (x,y) 2d plane using these angles.

Comment: But why do you want to get them from these angles? The second link I gave you shows how to get the position...

Comment: The reason for using the combination is to remove the drift and noise from all the sensors to get a precise result.