# How to get the android device Position and Pan via Sensors

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am currently working on the android app in which I need to stream the camera preview with some additional info to my server. Additional Information includes:

- Position: Device position in 3D space
- Pan: displacement in particular direction (Camera Panning)

I am able to stream the camera view but unable to find a solution for position and pan.

I tried [Read x y z coordinates of the android phone using accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068671/read-x-y-z-coordinates-of-android-phone-using-accelerometer) solution but it provides very inaccurate positions.

Please assist me how I will get the position and pan via sensors on the Android device.