# Tracking sideways movement on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, accelerometer

I am working with the accelerometer and gyroscope of the iPhone, but I am a bit confused.

I want to get values of straight movement on the three axis, not the rotation on them.
I seem to only get values of the latter...

How do I get usable values of the sideways and down/upwards motion of the device?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot get such usable values. I answered basicly the same question (Distance moved by Accelerometer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6648664/341970).