# how to retrieve location from accelerometer and magnetometer in android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, magnetometer

I want to retrieve the location and speed from accelerometer and magnetometer in the android device, I can currently get the speed from accelerometer, but how do I correlate it with the location from the magnetometer sensor, using both speed sensor and the geomagnetic field?

Comment: You can never detect speed with accelerometer, only acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

This question comes up [surprisingly often](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6648664/341970).

You cannot get accurate location or even velocity, but here are [tips what you actually could do instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970).