# Calculate distance Using UIAccelerometer in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am implementing an app which measures the how much distance it has moved .For example if my device felldown from my table to ground ,then I would like to calculate the distance.So Kindly help me to do this. Let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645126/distance-moved-by-accelerometer

Comment: depends on WHAT cases you want to measure, if you want to measure the distance your phone fell down then it is very easy. Why would anyone want to drop their phones beats me...

Comment: In case It fell down then I would like to inform them about the damage?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very clear : you want to compute the second level integral of the acceleration, which theorically is possible, by supposing the speed null at some time, but I really doubt you could get something precise enough to make any sense (as in many integral computations).

This isn't done today because the error is too big. Done in hardware (for permanent integration of the acceleration) it could be a little more precise but probably not enough to really compute a distance in any acceptable sense of the word "accuracy".

If you want to try it by yourself, here's a document describing more in detail the approach : http://perso-etis.ensea.fr/~pierandr/cours/M1_SIC/AN3397.pdf

Comment: If my iPhone felldown they how can I calculate the Gravitation(g) and Velocity? Please help me.

Comment: You don't compute the gravitation. You use the acceleration that you may multiply by the duration at any time do deduce the speed variation... and from the speed variation, supposing you had a null speed at start, you proceed similarly to compute the position... with an error so big it makes absolutely no sense.