# How can I measure the distance from the ground to the device?

Tags: android, height, distance, android-sensors, measure

For example, if I am 1,80m tall, maybe I am holding the phone at 1,60m from the ground when I'm standing. But is there any way to calculate it?

I have been looking for the different sensors that I can use to get info from the device, but I don't have any idea about how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically there is no sensor that is currently available in any phone that could measure absolute height/altitude to the degree you're asking (less than +/- 0.2 meters).  Most likely candidates:

-GPS has error range of about 3m

-Barometer measurements are relative to sea level and doubtful consumer grade e-barometers have anywhere near the level of sensitivity needed

You could measure relative distance however, if user were to say, drop his phone on the ground.  The Accelerometer could be used to calculate the distance using some approximation of g = 9.8 m/s²

Comment: Thanks, so I stop searching for the moment. I think the best option will be to introduce the approximate height by yourself according to you're height and assume some error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GPS or [accelerometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values)!
I think the same question is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221300/calculate-height-where-my-phone-is-being-held). 
I think it could help. Good luck with your challenge!

Comment: Yes, it is the same question, thank you. I had been searching with the tags distance from the ground, height... but I didn't find any. I'm going to have a look on this link. 

Mmm, it seems that it's only possible to do it moving the phone from the ground to X and calculating the distance according to the accelerometer data if you want something accurate. Maybe the best idea will be to introduce the distance to the ground manually and afford some error rate.